# How to give double quotes in onclick function of button?

Tags: javascript

After giving double quotes it is showing error

I am using google map api code in infowindow to open a page in iframe on button click.

```js
(function(marker, data) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
      infoWindow.setContent(data.description + "<br>" + 
      " <input type='button' class='class' value='More Details' onclick=@'document.getElementById('i').src = 'HomePage.aspx';' />" + 
      '<iframe id="i" style="height:50%;width:100%;"></iframe>');
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
```

Comment: What is `onclick=@'document.getElementById('i').src = 'HomePage.aspx';'` supposed to do?

Comment: After clicking on button Homepage.aspx will be opened in iframe whose id is ''i".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your weird syntax with @ means.

I would expect your code to be

```
infoWindow.setContent(data.description + '<br/>'+
'<input type="button" class="class" value="More Details" onclick="document.getElementById(\'i\').src = \'HomePage.aspx\'" />'+
'<iframe id="i" style="height:50%;width:100%;"></iframe>');
```